# Service placement on leader manager node in Docker Swarm

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

In a `docker-compose.yml` file, is there a way to [constrain the placement of a service](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/service_create/#specify-service-constraints---constraint) to not just a *manager* node, but the *leader* manager node?

For instance, this will constrain to any manager node:

```yaml
version: '3.5'
services:
  my_cool_service:
    image: meh
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints:
          - "node.role == manager"
```

Is there a similar constraint that provides functionality like:

```yaml
node.manager_status_leader == yes
```